# Mapping dicts based on key

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a `list` of `dict`s

```
input = [
  {'key': k1, 'value': v1},
  {'key': k1, 'value': v2},
  {'key': k2, 'value': v3}
]
```

What is the easiest way to to map these to the output

```
output == {k1: (v1, v2), k2: (v3)}
```

I don't really care about the order of the values. The best I've come up with is.

```
output = dict()
for i in input:
    temp = output.get(i['key'], [])
    temp.append(i['value'])
    output[i['key']] = temp
```

Any slick what of doing this with dict comprehension? I'm assuming the same process would work for a list of objects with attributes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a dict comprehension, any single key can only be accessed or modified once. In order to ensure that multiple values are paired with a single key, then, the values will need to be grouped in advance. A naive grouping solution will have, at best, quadratic performance. In fact, I can't come up with a one-liner that's better than cubic; it's an ugly beast, not even worth posting.

So an approach based on [`defaultdict`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29019131/577088) will almost always be best.

However, if your data is *guaranteed* to be sorted, or if you're willing to accept O(n log n) performance, then you could use `itertools.groupby`.

```
>>> input
[{'value': 1, 'key': 'a'}, {'value': 2, 'key': 'a'}, {'value': 3, 'key': 'b'}]
>>> {k:tuple(d['value'] for d in v) for k, v in
...  itertools.groupby(input, key=lambda d: d['key'])}
{'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3,)}
```

To get rid of the unsightly `lambda`, you could use `operator`.

```
>>> {k:tuple(d['value'] for d in v) for k, v in
...  itertools.groupby(input, key=operator.itemgetter('key'))}
{'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3,)}
```

Or, if you have to sort first:

```
>>> {k:tuple(d['value'] for d in v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(
...  sorted(input, key=operator.itemgetter('key')),
...  key=operator.itemgetter('key'))}
{'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3,)}
```

None of these solutions are very attractive; they all look a bit like abuses of comprehension syntax, with the possible exception of the second.

As an alternative to importing from `collections`, you can use `setdefault` -- though this produces lists rather than tuples:

```
>>> output = {}
>>> for d in input:
...     output.setdefault(d['key'], []).append(d['value'])
... 
>>> output
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3]}
```

Finally, consider this alternative -- I can't tell how I feel about it, but it does avoid all imports and exotic features, and produces tuples:

```
>>> output = {d['key']:() for d in input}
>>> for d in input:
...     output[d['key']] += (d['value'],)
... 
>>> output
{'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3,)}
```

Comment: Gotta love options! I don't mind the lists so I think I like the `setdefault` option the best. Seems to read the cleanest to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to loop over your dictionaries values then append them to `defaultdict` :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = defaultdict(tuple)
>>> for d in input:
...     a[d['key']] += (d['value'],)
... 
>>> a
defaultdict(<type 'tuple'>, {'k2': ('v3',), 'k1': ('v1', 'v2')})
```

Comment: I think you want `d.items()` instead of `d.values()`

Comment: @avim Notice that each dictionary in the list has exactly two values. The for loop iterates over the *pairs of values from each dictionary*, not the *key/value pairs*.

Comment: Your code works for that case. Dict is unordered container, therefore, the values are not guaranteed to be ordered as you think

Comment: @avim Ah. I see that now. I completely agree, but replacing `d.values()` with `d.items()` won't fix that. This answer would need significant changes to handle that (which it should).

Comment: Of course, I just mentioned the reason why this solution didn't do the job

Comment: The failure of this code isn't only hypothetical, but can be seen in practice: I get `defaultdict(<type 'tuple'>, {'v3': ('k2',), 'v2': ('k1',), 'v1': ('k1',)})` running it in Jython, for example.

Comment: Question on stackoverflow etiquette. Now that it's edited, was first, and is pretty damn straightforward should I switch my checkmark? Personally I'll probably use the list solution mentioned above, but based on subjective criteria (don't care about lists and would rather use normal dicts), but I put those nowhere in the original question. Thoughts?